# Ruby undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Loop in a loop

Tags: ruby, loops

Basically I'm looping through a matrix of arrays adding up the columns, but it stops right before the 2nd iteration of the `9.times` loop. If I change `y = 1` it will perform the action and stop at `y = 2` and so on.

```
def new_feature(board)
  x=0
  y=0
  vertical = []
    while y < 9
      9.times do
        vertical << board[x][y]
        x += 1
      end
     puts vertical.reduce(:+)
     vertical = []
     y += 1 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never reset `x` back to 0, so in the second `while` iteration your `x` starts with `9` where it finished last time, not `0`. This makes `board[9]`, which is presumably out of bounds and thus `nil`; and then `nil[1]` crashes your code.

Note that you can write `9.times do |x| ... end` to have `x` count from `0` to `8` without any manual counting, since `times` passes the current iteration number into the block.

Also, a more Rubyish way to sum columns:

```
board.transpose.map { |row| row.reduce(&:+) }
```